# No matching constructor when I overload operator for dynamic string class

Tags: c++, string, dynamic-allocation

I get a problem with my String class.

Constructor and copy constructor:

```
private:
    char * buf;
public:
    String( const char * s = "")
    {
        buf = strdup(s);
    }
    String( String &s)
    : buf(strdup(s.buf))
    {
    }
```

The operator:

```
String operator + ( const String &s )
{
    char* tmp = new char[strlen(buf) + strlen(s.buf) + 1]; // +1 for the terminating '\0'
    strcpy(tmp,buf);
    strcat(tmp,s.buf);
    String result;
    delete[] result.buf;
    result.buf = tmp;
    return result;
}
String operator += ( const String s )
{
    delete_char_array(buf);
    char* tmp = new char[strlen(buf) + strlen(s.buf) + 1];
    strcpy(tmp,buf);
    strcat(tmp,s.buf);
    buf = strdup(tmp);
    delete_char_array(tmp);
    return *this;
}
void print( ostream & out )
{
    char *p = buf;
    out << p;
}
```

and I have implemented the << operator

```
ostream & operator << ( ostream & out,  String str )
{
    str.print(out);
    return out;
}
```

My main() function is:

```
int main()
{
    String firstString("First");
    String secondString("Second");
    cout << firstString + secondString << endl;
    (firstString+=secondString).print(cout);
}
```

I can correctly get the output by the String.print(cout) but the g++ will tell me that

```
cout << firstString + secondString << endl;` does not have the matching
constructor for `String::String(String)`
```

and there are two options, 1. `String::String( char * c)` and 2. `String::String(String &s)`.

Comment: Use `const` in the copy constructor: `String(const String &s)`

Comment: You're using `strdup` in your constructor, and then you mix in `new[]` in your other functions.  So what is your destructor going to look like?  The `strdup` returns a pointer that is deallocated using `free()`, not `delete[]`.  Why didn't you just use `new[]` in the constructor also?

Comment: Also, operator `+=` should be returning a reference to the current object, not a brand new String object.  In addition, `operator +` can be written in terms of `operator +=` -- there is no need for code duplication.  In short, there are a few more issues with your class besides the copy constructor.

Answer (score 3):

This should be the copy constructor signature:

```
String(String const& s)
```

so the reference can bind to an r-value returned by `operator+`. Additionally, you should also use this signature for `operator<<`:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, String const& str)
```

Any of these snippets will fix the error, however (1) is a crucial practice (as you see) and (2) avoids making a copy.

You'll also need to make `void print(ostream &out) const`, because you want to call it with `String const&`, even `operator+` should be `const`. Please, don't forget the `const`...

You don't modify a reference - make it a reference-to-const. A member function does not modify `*this` - make it `const`. It's that simple.

<sup>You also forgot an `&` here: `String operator+=(const String s)`.</sup>

**We're still not finished, there's also a number of things to fix, as pointed out in PaulMcKenzie's comments.**

Comment: After adding the const in operator <<, the compiler tells me that member function 'print' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const 
  String', but function is not marked const

Comment: `operator +=` should really be returning a `String&` and then the return would be `return *this;`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, I've added a reference to avoid making a copy :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your `String` class.

First, usage of `strdup` returns an allocated buffer that should be deallocated using `free()`.  However in your overloaded `+=` and `+` functions, you're using `new []` and `delete []`.   You're using C++, so *pretend that strdup() doesn't exist*.

Even though you're trying to be careful about it, it is undefined behavior to mix allocation functions like this.  Instead, use `new []` and `delete []` throughout your class code.

Second, the copy constructor signature should be:

```
    String(const String &s);
```

So your constructors should now look like this:

```
private:
    char * buf;
public:
    String( const char* s = "") : buf(new char[strlen(s) + 1]())
    {
        strcpy(buf, s);
    }

    String(const String &s) : buf(new char[strlen(s.buf) + 1]())
    {
        strcpy(buf, s.buf);
    }
```

You now need to add a destructor, if you haven't done so already:

```
String::~String() { delete [] buf; }
```

Next is your `operator +=` and `operator +`.  The `operator +=` should be returning a reference to the current object, not a brand new object.

```
String& operator += ( const String& s )
{
    char* tmp = new char[strlen(buf) + strlen(s.buf) + 1];
    strcpy(tmp,buf);
    strcat(tmp,s.buf);
    delete [] buf;
    buf = tmp;
    return *this;
}
```

Note that the return type is a reference to `String`.  Also, note that the memory for the concatenated string is allocated first before any attempt is made to delete the old buffer.  This needs to be done to ensure that your buffer will not become invalidated if `operator new` throws an exception.

Given this, `operator +` can be written this way:

```
String operator + ( const String& s )
{
    String tmp(*this);
    return tmp += s;
}
```

We use `operator +=` as a helper function.  All that was done was to create a temporary `String` that was the same as `*this`.  Then we just return the result of `operator +=` on the passed in `String`.  Short and simple.

The last thing you're missing is an assignment operator. Without an assignment operator, you cannot safely do things like this:

```
String s1("abc");
String s2;
s2 = s1; // <-- assignment operator here
```

To implement an assignment operator is very easy, provided you have a copy constructor and working destructor.  Please go to this link as to how to implement this function:

[copy / swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).